# What font configuration is used by microtype documentation

Tags: fonts, documentation, microtype

I really like the font configuration (appearance) of the documentation for `microtype` package (see [here](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/)). How do I find out the combination they're using? (I will fix the protrusion etc later but first I need to select the fonts etc. that they're using.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can look at the source code for the documentation here: http://mirrors.xmu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.dtx

Comment: The specific lines you're looking for: "Let's abolish CM! We use Charter and Letter Gothic (for the pre-built documentation on CTAN): `\usepackage[charter]{`[`mathdesign`](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/mathdesign-doc.pdf)`}`.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't have access to document sources, some pdf viewers can show you what fonts are used. I've tested with AdobeReader and PDF-XChange-viewer and under Properties of the document you will find the list of fonts. Here you have the output from microtype manual under Xchange-viewer.

Just a problem, then you need to find how to use them in your document.

[image]

Comment: On Linux you could also use the `pdffonts` command and/or the `pdfinfo` command

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had to accept the other answer though because that was the direct one to the question.