# Mimicking the Microtype documentation

Tags: typography, microtype

One of the nicest LaTeX examples I have seen is the [Microtype documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf).

The `.dtx` file is available [here](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.dtx) and I have been trying to recreate a document looking like this. Unfortunately it's not super clear to me how to recreate a similar document from the `.dtx` file.

I am using

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{ltxdoc}
```

which is straight from the `.dtx` file. Is that the package from the original `.tex` file?

I'm also interested in recreating the color scheme and margin notes!

Comment: I especially like the [font used in the microtype docmentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38213/what-font-configuration-is-used-by-microtype-documentation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ltxdoc` class is the standard LaTeX documentation class. The `microtype` documentation just extends this class via a number of macros defined in the preamble. Copy everything from the 
preamble to emulate the looks of the documentation package.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
   copy up to line 647
\begin{document}
```

You can then remove carefully any definitions you might not want that are specific to the `microtype` documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that wasn't going to be the answer :)