# I need to change color of beamer itemize and subitem separately?

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

I have a dummy beamer, and I want to replicate the bullet style.

Also, if someone can tell me what is the font used, it would be great!

[image]

The following is not working for me:

`\documentclass[serif]{beamer}   \usepackage{mathpazo,setspace,amsmath,graphicx,color,multirow,enumerate,mathtools}      \usetheme{CambridgeUS}  \usecolortheme{dolphin} \title{Random Variables and Expectations}  \useoutertheme{tree}  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection} \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}`

Comment: Hier are the commands to address the foreground color separately: `\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}`

Comment: apparently this doesnt work with ball or i am having some compiling error...!

Comment: \documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}\usepackage{enumerate}
\title[]{Random Variables and Expectations}
\subtitle{}
\author{}
\institute[]{}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red} \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}
*******Not Working **********

Comment: @Nikhil: Please add that code to your original post, perhaps below the screenshot, not in a comment.

Comment: You're using Adobe Reader then [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38236/1952) can help you to find the font used

Comment: @ Ignasi - Thanks! I need to see if this is the one. Its shows Times New Roman..! I don't think its the default Times New Roman...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The itemize items ball templates are defined in the `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`:

```
% Itemize items, ball

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{ball}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{ball}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{subitem projected}{smallsphere}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{ball}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{subsubitem projected}{smallsphere}}
```

If you want to change the color for itemize *and* enumerate you can use

```
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{subitem projected}{bg=green}
```

If you want to change *only* itemize (and not enumerate) then use

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{bg=green}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize item}{bigsphere}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize subitem}{smallsphere}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usefonttheme{serif} % serif fonts for the entire beamer
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate} % To change the ennumerate style
\useoutertheme{tree}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty %supressing navigation bar
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

% change the item and subitem color separatly (itemize and enumerate)
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{subitem projected}{bg=green}

%%% change the item and subitem color separatly (only itemize)
%%\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{bg=red}
%%\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{bg=green}
%%\makeatletter
%%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize item}{bigsphere}}
%%\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.2pt\beamer@usesphere{itemize subitem}{smallsphere}}
%%\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Probability}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Probability} expresses a degree of belief a person has about an event or a statement by a number between zero and one. 
    \item \textbf{Two Schools of Statistical Inference:}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \textit{Bayesian Inference} - common usage.
      \item \textit{Classical Inference} - The classical statistician uses the word probability only for an event which can be repeated, and interprets it as the limit of the empirical frequency of the event as the number of repititions increases indefinitely.
    \end{itemize}
    \item The two methods are complimentary and diferent situations call for different methods.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much! :) Somehow it wasn't coming up! Now i got it! :)